# Changing callback into a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

I was trying to start using promise chaining (was using callbacks so far), and I wanted to edit this code:

```
Account.findById(req.user._id,
    (err, acc) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var r = req.body;
        acc.fullName = r.fullName;
        acc.displayname = r.username;
        acc.city = r.city;
        acc.province = r.province;
        acc.postalCode = r.postalCode;
        acc.phone = r.phone;
        acc.ageGroup = r.ageGroup;
        acc.education = r.education;
        acc.lookingForWork = r.lookingForWork;
        acc.employmentStatus = r.employmentStatus;
        acc.workingWithEOESC = r.workingWithEOESC;
        acc.resume = r.resume;
        acc.mainWorkExp = r.mainWorkExp;
        acc.save();
        res.redirect('/seeker');
    })
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
Account.findById(req.user._id)
    .then((err, acc) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var r = req.body;
        acc.fullName = r.fullName;
        acc.displayname = r.username;
        acc.city = r.city;
        acc.province = r.province;
        acc.postalCode = r.postalCode;
        acc.phone = r.phone;
        acc.ageGroup = r.ageGroup;
        acc.education = r.education;
        acc.lookingForWork = r.lookingForWork;
        acc.employmentStatus = r.employmentStatus;
        acc.workingWithEOESC = r.workingWithEOESC;
        acc.resume = r.resume;
        acc.mainWorkExp = r.mainWorkExp;
        acc.save();
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
    .then((acc) => {
        console.log(acc);
        res.redirect('/seeker');
    })
});
```

But the promise version throws a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullName' of undefined` error.

The changes are not being saved and console loging the `acc` results in `undefined`. Forgot to add that in the post

I'm just learning promises. What am I missing? The inside code is almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` functions in promises can take maxiumum two argument which must be both functions, the first function is when the promise is fullfilled, while the second function is when the promise is rejected, alternatively you can pass in only one function to `.then` and use `.catch` to handle any kind of error or a rejected promise

```
var f1 = acc => console.log(acc); // logs out the acc object;
var f2 = err => console.log(err); // logs out error while executing the promise

.then(f1,f2); // when you do this there is no need for a catch block

// or

.then( acc => {
    console.log(acc) // logs out the acc object
 }).catch( err => console.log(err) ) //logs out the error


 // if you need to handle another value

 .then( acc => {
      console.log(acc);
      return acc.save(); //lets say acc.save() returns an object
  }).then( acc => console.log(acc) ); // the value of acc.save() is passed down to the next `.then` block
```

Answer (score 2):

Callback-based API's have a common convention of using the first argument of the callback function to indicate failure. Promises require no such convention, because they have built-in means of handling failures, so you need to just operate on the first argument, not the second. The second argument will be `undefined`, resulting in the error you're seeing.

Most of the time when you're translating callback-based code to promise-based code, you want to use this pattern as your basic guide:

```
// Callback-based:
asyncFn((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // handle failure
    } else {
        // handle success
    }
});


// Promise-based equivalent:
asyncFnPromise()
    .then((result) => {
        // handle success
    }, (err) => {
        // handle failure
    });


// Alternative promised-based:
asyncFnPromise()
    .then((result) => {
        // handle success.
        // Note that unlike the above, any errors thrown here will trigger
        // the `catch` handler below, in addition to actual asyncFnPromise
        // failures.
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // handle failure
    });
```

Comment: How is this different from my not working code? I'm just trying to find my errors

Comment: Look at the second line of your attempted promise-based code. You have two arguments in the function you're providing to `then`. You should only have one.

Comment: Remove the error checking stuff from that function. Error checking should be handled in a separate function, either in the second argument of `then` (my second example) or in a `catch` (my third example)

Answer (score 0):

`then` is just called on success, therefore there is definetly no error:

```
 then((acc) => {
```

Comment: The changes are not being saved and console loging the `acc` results in `undefined`. Forgot to add that in the post

Comment: @alex3wielki maybe the Account doesnt exist yet?

Comment: The code is in the exact same place. Account is declared at the top

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the function 'findById' probably not returning 'promise' and just returning some response.You need to create a 'promise object' in findById function and return it.

```
findById (){
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
  Suppose results is yield from some async task, so when
  //wanted results occured
    resolve(value);

  //unwanted result occured
    reject(new Error('Something happened!'));

  return promise;
}



findById.then(response => {
   console.log(response);
}, error => {
   console.log(error);
});
```